# Does this function have a name? What other properties does it have?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

Let $x < y$ be real numbers and let $ a$ satisfy $0<a<1$, Does the function $ z = a y +(1-a)x$ have a name?

What properties does this function have?

This particular function has come up a few times recently while I have been studying and I have noticed that is has some nice properties.

For instance:

$$(1-a)(z-x)=a(y-z)$$

It is also used in the Definition of a Convex function:

A function $g$ is said to be convex on an interval $[a,b]$ if, for all x and y in $[a,b]$ and for every $a$ satisfying $0<a<1$ , we have:

$$ g(z)=a\,g(y) + (1-a)\,g(x)\: \:where \:z = a y +(1-a)x $$

Comment: I would call $z(a)$ the [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation#Linear_interpolation) between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It's part of a plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In higher-dimensional settings it's common to call
$$
z(t) = (1 - t)x + ty = x + t(y - x)
\tag{1}
$$
the [*convex linear combination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of $x$ and $y$. If $x$ and $y$ are elements of a normed vector space $(V, \| \cdot \|)$, the mapping $z$ is the unique constant-speed parametrization of the line through $x$ and $y$ normalized so that $z(0) = x$ and $z(1) = y$.

Geometrically, $z$ scales the number line by a factor $\|y - x\|$, then includes it isometrically into $V$ in such a way that $[0, 1]$ is sent to the segment from $x$ to $y$. These geometric interpretations hold for $V = \mathbf{R}$, as well, which explains this expression's appearance when you consider convex functions, or parametrizations of general intervals.